# Mixed Content Laravel Ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, laravel, nginx

Проблема появилась когда перенесли с хостинга на впс

Вот урл запроса

```
https://site/goats-menu/api/main-page-goat-descriptions/
```

Вот код

```
ajax: {
            url: '/goats-menu/api/main-page-goat-descriptions/',
            type: "GET",
            headers: authHeaders,
        },
```

Пробовал уберать последний слэш - не помагает

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Из за того что location http - у меня блокируется запрос

Подскажите как бороться с этим?

Вот собственно ошибка

> Mixed Content: The page at
> 'https://site/goats-menu/main-page-goat-descriptions' was
> loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure XMLHttpRequest endpoint
> 'http://site/goats-menu/api/main-page-goat-descriptions.
> This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.
> Цитата

Comment: А как вы урл подставляете?

Comment: @Walfter вот так: url: '/goats-menu/api/main-page-goat-descriptions/'

Comment: Я не о том малость. В общем. Посмотрите урлы в окружении `APP_URL` и `ASSET_URL`

Comment: @Walfter а - там тоже через https

Comment: @Walfter все скрипты и стили - подключаються через https